# Elasticsearch - find IPs from which only anonymous requests came

Tags: elasticsearch

I have network logs in my Elasticsearch. Each log has an username and an IP field. Something like this:

```
{"username":"user1", "ip": "1.2.3.4"}
{"username":"anonymous", "ip": "1.2.3.4"}
{"username":"anonymous", "ip": "2.3.4.5"}
{"username":"user2", "ip": "3.4.5.6"}
```

I have a seemingly simple task: list all IP-s from which only anonymous requests came. The problem is, I can not simply filter for anonymous, because then I'll list false IP-s which appear with anonymous, but not exclusively. Manually I can do this with a 3 step process:

1. List all unique IP-s
2. List unique IP-s that appear with something other than anonymous
3. Exclude items of 2nd list from the first.

But is there a way to do this with a single ES query? My first instinct was to use bool query. My current approach is this:

```
GET /sample1/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {
        "wildcard": {
          "ip": "*"
        }
      },
        "must_not": {
          "term": {
            "username": "-anonymous"
          }
        }
      }
  },
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "ips": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "ip.keyword"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I expect "2.3.4.5", but it returns all 3 unique IPs. I searched the web and tried different query types for hours. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please find the below mapping, sample docs, the respective query for your scenario and the response:

### Mapping:

```
PUT my_ip_index
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "user":{
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "ip":{
        "type": "ip"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

### Documents:

```
POST my_ip_index/_doc/1
{
  "user": "user1",
  "ip": "1.2.3.4"
}

POST my_ip_index/_doc/2
{
  "user": "anonymous",
  "ip": "1.2.3.4"
}

POST my_ip_index/_doc/3
{
  "user": "anonymous",
  "ip": "2.3.4.5"
}

POST my_ip_index/_doc/4
{
  "user": "user2",
  "ip": "3.4.5.6"
}
```

### Aggregation Query:

```
POST my_ip_index/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "my_valid_ips": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "ip",
        "size": 10
      },
      "aggs": {
        "valid_users": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "user",
            "size": 10,
            "include": "anonymous"
          }
        },
        "min_bucket_selector": {
          "bucket_selector": {
            "buckets_path": {
              "valid_users_count": "valid_users._bucket_count",
              "my_valid_ips_count": "_count"
            },
            "script": {
              "source": "params.valid_users_count == 1 && params.my_valid_ips_count == 1"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Note how I've made use of [Terms Aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.htm) and [Bucket Selector Aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-pipeline-bucket-selector-aggregation.html) in the above query.

I've added `include` part in Terms Agg so as to consider only `anonymous` users and the logic inside bucket aggregation is to filter out only if it is a single doc count in the top level terms aggregation for e.g. `2.3.4.5` followed by single bucket count in the second level terms aggregation.

### Response:

```
{
  "took" : 1,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 4,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : null,
    "hits" : [ ]
  },
  "aggregations" : {
    "my_valid_ips" : {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
      "buckets" : [
        {
          "key" : "2.3.4.5",                 <---- Expected IP/Answer
          "doc_count" : 1,
          "valid_users" : {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
            "buckets" : [
              {
                "key" : "anonymous",
                "doc_count" : 1
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Also welcome to SOF, if you think your query has been resolved, feel free to upvote the answer by clicking on the up arrow key you see at the start of the answer **and/or** accept the answer by clicking the greyed out tick mark that is just under it.

Comment: It works, Thank you! I didn't expect to get an answer this quickly. The solution is more complex than anticipated, looks like there is still much to go on the ES learning curve for me.